# 4 logically isolated networks anyway to setup 1 with access to all networks?

Tags: networking

I just recently switched careers and entered the IT field. My new boss tasked me with finding out if it is possible with his current network setup, which is 4 logical networks isolated, to have 1 of the networks have access to all of them.

Comment: What kind of equipment do you have? Are you wanting to keep the others isolated and have one 'super' network that has access at all? I'd say you're looking for VLANs.

Comment: Good point, I assumed he had separate buildings but that may not be the case. If it's in one building then VLANS is a very good sugestion

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, but you will need to learn about subnetting. It's a bit of a read but it's very useful. You can find an article here http://www.techrepublic.com/article/ip-subnetting-made-easy/ or google it.

Edit: I would also reading as much as you can about TCP/IP protocol as you are new to the industry. Tell your boss to pay for a COMPTIA A+ and CCNA training course, you will learn everything there.